# Vue CLI 3 --modern mode build => error in browser

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli-3

```
chunk-vendors.60d43f55.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'webpackJsonp' of undefined
at chunk-vendors.60d43f55.js:1
```

=> chunk-vendors.60d43f55.js:1
[image]

index.html => 
[image]

Without --modern mode all works correctly

Answer (score 2):

Ah, I found issue in my vue.config.js =>
redundant globalObject: 'this'

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  configureWebpack: {
    output: {
      globalObject: 'this'
    }
  }
  ...
}
```